# std::find with two different types

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, operator-overloading

I am trying to use std::find with two different types but providing the necessary boolean operators.

```
class FooDetails
{
public:
    FooDetails(int size = 5)
    : m_size(size) { /* empty */ }
    bool operator<(const FooDetails& other) const { return m_size < other.m_size; }
    bool operator==(const FooDetails& other) const { return m_size == other.m_size; }
private:
    int m_size;
};

class Foo
{
public:
    Foo(int size)
    : m_details(size) { /* empty */}

    bool operator==(const Foo& other) const { return m_details == other.m_details; }
    bool operator==(const FooDetails& other) const {return m_details == other; }
    bool operator<(const Foo& other) const { return m_details < other.m_details; }
    bool operator<(const FooDetails& other) const { return m_details < other; }
    FooDetails m_details;
};

bool operator==(const FooDetails& lhs, const Foo& rhs) { return lhs == rhs.m_details; }
bool operator==(const Foo& lhs, const FooDetails& rhs) {return lhs.m_details == rhs; }
bool operator<(const FooDetails& lhs, const Foo& rhs) { return lhs < rhs.m_details; }
bool operator<(const Foo& lhs, const FooDetails& rhs) { return lhs.m_details < rhs; }

int main() {
    std::vector<Foo> haystack = { FooDetails(5), FooDetails(6), FooDetails(7) };

    FooDetails needle(6);
    std::find(haystack.begin(), haystack.end(), needle);
    return 0;
}
```

Since std::find uses operator== I would expect this to work, since all necessary functions are provided. However this does not compile. Why is that and how do I fix it?
I know I could use std::find_if, but I assume that's a bit slower and even if it's not I'd like to know why std::find doesn't work.

Comment: And what is the error *exactly*? And on what line.

Comment: You have the `operator==` twice, so the compiler doesn't know which one to choose. Just comment out one.
Next Mistake is initialization of haystack of type `Foo` with types `FooDetails`

Answer (score 4):

I've changed your code to this:

```
#include <algorithm>

class FooDetails
{
public:
    FooDetails(int size = 5)
    : m_size(size) { /* empty */ }
    bool operator<(const FooDetails& other) const { return m_size < other.m_size; }
    bool operator==(const FooDetails& other) const { return m_size == other.m_size; }
private:
    int m_size;
};

class Foo
{
public:
    Foo(int size)
    : m_details(size) { /* empty */}

    FooDetails m_details;
};

bool operator==(const FooDetails& lhs, const Foo& rhs) { return lhs == rhs.m_details; }
bool operator==(const Foo& lhs, const FooDetails& rhs) {return lhs.m_details == rhs; }
bool operator<(const FooDetails& lhs, const Foo& rhs) { return lhs < rhs.m_details; }
bool operator<(const Foo& lhs, const FooDetails& rhs) { return lhs.m_details < rhs; }

int main() {
    std::vector<Foo> haystack = { Foo(5), Foo(6), Foo(7) };

    FooDetails needle(6);
    std::find(haystack.begin(), haystack.end(), needle);
    return 0;
}
```

And it successfully compiles. Your original version contains two errors:

1. You try to create `std::vector<Foo>` initialising it with `std::initialization_list<FooDetails>`.
2. You have provided **too many** comparison operators: both free versions and members of the Foo struct. So during lookup compiler complains that it doesn't know which one of them to choose. You should leave only one of them.

Comment: Great, thank you. The initialization of the vector was a typo from the example ofcourse. I didn't realize I could have too many comparison operators though. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You have no such constructor in `Foo` class which constructs it from `FooDetails`. You need to define the following and your code will work:

```
Foo(const FooDetails& d) : m_details(d) {}
```

Comment: I know that it will work like this, but I thought it should also work if I only provide the appropriate comparison operators. Cause with the constructor solution I assume that for every search a Foo object will be constructed which should have a performance impact, right?

Comment: The constructor is necessary to initialize your `std::vector<Foo> haystack` from `FooDetails` objects. The `std::find` won't construct new `Foo` objects because you overloaded the comparsion operator for `Foo` and `FooDetails` so the compiler doesn't need to implicitly convert a `FooDetails` to `Foo` for comparsion.

Comment: Yeah, as I said, that was just a typo.